# how to create a conditional break point in ipdb

Tags: python, ipython, spyder

I am using python version 3.7.1 in spyder.

When I run a script and I need to debug I simply enter the line below the line before where an error happens.

> breakpoint()

So far for my basic needs this has been sufficient. I can see the current values of the variables or type commands in the ipdb> command line section.

However I can't work out how to use a conditional break point? I have tried reading various sites but don't quite understand what I need to do. They also tend to mention pdb not ipdb. How can I use a conditional break point?

Comment: Have you tried putting it under an if statement? `if my_condition: breakpoint()`

Comment: No I understand that will work but I'm trying to get used to using debugging in python. In other languages it seems a bit easier

Comment: Conditional breakpoints are really easy with IDEs but with ipython I'd guess it's harder to implement (or out of project scope), seeing how it's a frontend to the Python console. If you want better control over the flow of your code, you should try PyCharm Community Edition (free for all), or if you're a student you could even use PyCharm Professional for free.

Comment: `pdb` itself has a syntax for this, which you can use in `ipdb`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55159862/71631

Answer (score 0):

I think @billc's comment above is what OP was looking for. In the console, you enter

`b <line number>, <condition to break under>`

For example:
`b C:\Users\powlo\project\tests\TestCase.py:350, view.view_name == 'app.views.export'`
[Example from @powlo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55159862/71631)

official docs here
https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html#pdbcommand-break